# create an OAuth client in c# for automation testing

Tags: c#, automation, oauth-2.0

I am trying to test againt a service that implements the OAuth 2.0 authentication protocol and I want to run the automation without using any browser elements. Is that possible and if so how?

What i am currently doing is opening a browser and then sending user/key combination and then on redirect, I get the access token from the URL which I then use in subsequent REST calls. but this method takes a bit of time and may not be completely reliable for running lots of tests.

Is there any way that I can programatically handle the initial handshake, i.e, send the user/key, get the permission request page and then accept it through c# as well and finally get the access token without any browser in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

Check out DotNetOpenAuth - http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

You should be able to write automated test cases quite simply

Answer (score 0):

You could try service account authentication for your test system. This approach replaces user interaction with cryptographically signed JSON Web Tokens (JWTs).

[Google's implementation docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount) have some details.

Comment: From what I read, it seems this needs to have a server change. unfortunately I think the service I am using may not support JWTs and changing it wouldnt really be feasible at this point and isnt under my control. Is it a part of the OAuth spec of something google supports as an addition to minimum requirements